# How can I use ':' character in a name of XDocument element?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml, special-characters

I'm using XDocument to create a RSS same below code:

```
var document = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("rss",
                 new XElement("channel",
                              new XElement("title", "test"),
                              new XElement("dc:creator", "test"),
```

An exception occurring during the execution of this code.

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

How can I use `:` character in a name of element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XNamespace to create nicely formatted XML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572243/using-xnamespace-to-create-nicely-formatted-xml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use namespaces, you'll need to create the namespace object first:

**UPDATED**

```
XNamespace ns = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";
var document = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
            new XElement("rss", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dc", ns)
                         new XElement("channel",
                                      new XElement("title", "test"),
                                      new XElement(ns + "creator", "test"),
            ....
```

Comment: And you'll also note that ':' isn't used, instead you concatenate the namespace with the element's name (which results in an XName).

Comment: the result of this solution is <creator xmlns="dc"> but I need <dc:creator>

Comment: the 2 are equivalent, 'dc:' is just a short way of using an already aliased xml namespace (as declared using xmlns:dc="...")

Comment: @user667429, I updated the answer to format it as you requested

Comment: If you want to actually see <dc:... in the output, you will have to add the appropriate xmlns for dc, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340096/xelement-add-an-xmlns