# Add namespace with colon to xml file

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xelement, xnamespace

I need to generate a xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:Root xmlns:ns0="http://namespace">
  <Node1>
    <A>ValueA</A>
    <B>ValueB</B>
  </Node1>
</Root>
```

This is my code:

```
const string ns = "http://namespace";
var xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", ns),
        new XElement("Node1",
            new XElement("A", "ValueA"),
            new XElement("B", "ValueB")
        )
    )
);
```

But this produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:ns0="http://namespace">
  <Node1>
    <A>ValueA</A>
    <B>ValueB</B>
  </Node1>
</Root>
```

Note the missing "ns0:" before the Root node. How can I add it? Everything else should be exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried to put `"ns:Root"` instead `"Root"` as parameter of first `XElement` constructor?

Comment: @HuorSwords: does not work, I get "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name" exception.

Comment: Please, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6125645/982431) for a similar (even not equal) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://namespace");

var xDocument = new XDocument(
                new XElement(ns + "Root",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns0", ns),
                    new XElement("Node1",
                        new XElement("A", "ValueA"),
                        new XElement("B", "ValueB")
                        )));
```